# How to find day of the week from known date and month but variable year

Tags: vba, excel

My code so far is this:

> ```
> intYear = CDate(varYear)  
> intJan = Weekday("1/1/" & intYear)
> ```

varYear is a variant that has been tested to be a valid number.

The problem is in line two, it doesn't like me trying to merge the date and month to the variable year, is there another way around this?

Edit:
I have since changed the code to this:

> ```
> varJan = ("1/1/" & varYear)  
> intJan = Weekday(CDate(varJan))
> ```

It is still having trouble, it's saying there's a type mismatch. I know the issue is steaming again from the second line.

Comment: It's working as is for me.  Are you sure about your `varYear` value?

Comment: You write: *varYear is a variant that has been tested to be a valid **number***.  It would be more to the point if varYear were a valid **Date**

Comment: intJan = Weekday("1/1/" & varYear) is working fine for me. Check this.

Comment: As @PareshJ wrote, don't convert your year to a date, just use `"1/1/" & varYear` directly.

Comment: Try `intJan = Weekday(DateSerial(varYear,1,1))`

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I played with the variable types until it worked. I don't currently have access to my work computer but will edit the question to include the solution as soon as I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found by eliminating unnecessary variables and thus eliminating potential conversion problems.
The final code was as follows:

> intJan = Weekday(CDate("1/1/" & varYear))

Comment: `CDate` is sometimes confused by ambiguous dates. It may guess incorrectly when deciding if you use m/d/y or d/m/y format.  That is why I recommend DateSerial(Year, Month, Day). An alternative is to place # at start and end of string which specifies it as American Civilian format if that is what you want.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment Tony, this proved very useful information when later troubleshooting another area of my code.